# Firebase Auth with new Apple's opt-out from social login

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

New Apple guidelines state that users should be able to opt-out from social login and switch to email login.

With Facebook and Twitter login I added email login. Now, in settings view, I want to add this option for social login opt-out and I don't really get how Firebase works in this case.

I have a view for creating a new account and I imagine after successful account creation I just need to delete (unlink) the old provider.

This is my code so far:

```
Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user, error) in
    guard let user = user else {
        if let error = error as NSError? {
            Alertift.alert(title: "", message: error.localizedDescription)
                .action(.default("Okay"))
                .show(on: self, completion: nil)
        }
        return
    }

    if self.isInOptOut {
        // Opt-Out flow
        print("OPT-OUT FLOW")
        let credential = EmailAuthProvider.credential(withEmail: email, password: password)
        user.user.linkAndRetrieveData(with: credential, completion: { (result, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
                Alertift.alert(title: "", message: error.localizedDescription)
                    .action(.default("Okay"))
                    .show(on: self, completion: nil)
            }

            guard let result = result else {
                return
            }

            print(result)
        })
    }

    // Regular flow, go through form
    let userProfileFormViewController = UserProfileFormViewController()
    userProfileFormViewController.email = user.user.email
    userProfileFormViewController.isEmailDisabled = true
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(userProfileFormViewController, animated: true)
}
```

I get the error that user already uses this provider. Can somebody please point me in a right direction?

UPDATE:

I managed to make this work with different ordering.

```
if self.isInOptOut {
            guard let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser else { print("No user"); return }

            // Link with email provider

            let credential = EmailAuthProvider.credential(withEmail: email, password: password)
            currentUser.linkAndRetrieveData(with: credential, completion: { (authResult, error) in
                if let error = error {
                    Alertift.alert(title: "", message: error.localizedDescription)
                        .action(.default("Okay"))
                        .show(on: self, completion: nil)
                }

                // Unlink from Social provider
                if currentUser.providerData.count > 0 {
                    for provider in currentUser.providerData {
                        print(provider.providerID)
                        if provider.providerID == "twitter.com" || provider.providerID == "facebook.com" {
                            currentUser.unlink(fromProvider: provider.providerID) { (user, error) in
                                Alertift.alert(title: "", message: "Success. From now on, use only email login.")
                                    .action(.default("I understand"), handler: { _, _, _ in
                                        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
                                    })
                                    .show(on: self, completion: nil)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You error is happening because you create a new account with email authentication for the user and then you try to merge, from the documentation:

> The call to linkWithCredential:completion: will fail if the credentials are already linked to another user account.

i.e You are trying to use the same credentials on two different accounts.

Delete the `.createUser`. Upon successful `.linkAndRetrieveData` login the user with email provider and unlink the social provider.

Comment: I rearranged my function. I will post it in my question, maybe it will help somebody.